# removing data within specific delimiters in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have some data where the cells in one particular column look like this:

`[SOME.LAST.NAME, SOME.FIRST.NAME 1] SOME.ADDRESS 1; [SOME.LAST.NAME, SOME.FIRST.NAME 2] SOME.ADDRESS 2`

How do I remove anything thats found within, and including, the square brackets `[]` to create a cell that looks like the following?

`SOME ADDRESS 1; SOME ADDRESS 2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` with `\\[.*?\\]` to *remove anything that's found within, and including, the square brackets []*:

```
x <- "[SOME.LAST.NAME, SOME.FIRST.NAME 1] SOME.ADDRESS 1; [SOME.LAST.NAME, SOME.FIRST.NAME 2] SOME.ADDRESS 2"
gsub("\\[.*?\\]", "", x)
#[1] " SOME.ADDRESS 1;  SOME.ADDRESS 2"
```

In case you also want to remove some spaces use:

```
trimws(gsub(" *\\[.*?\\]", "", x))
#[1] "SOME.ADDRESS 1; SOME.ADDRESS 2"
```